# Is Team Foundation Server designed to utilize Sql Server Filestream?

Tags: sql-server, tfs, filestream

I'm trying to allay concerns over keeping website artifacts in TFS due to their size, and I was hoping I could add FILESTREAM to the discussion. And, while this is a question that has been asked before, it's been asked only infrequently and been given only vague answers. I found [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsadmin/thread/19b7a620-7dfb-4f35-b973-2fa5d0130156) that raises the issue, but the answer came from someone outside of Microsoft, and was answered empirically to boot. Unfortunately, that's been some of the only direct treatment I can find on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have an idea of the size of the artefacts?

What is the purpose of the artefacts? If they are artefacts that are required to be version controlled then put them in TFS. If they do not require version control then put them in your DML.

Whilst this doesn't directly answer your question, these blog posts should give you some insight in to the inner workings of TFS.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2009/05/31/devdiv-tfs-database-sizes.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2009/07/13/tfs-database-sizes-for-a-somewhat-more-normal-team.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billheys/archive/2011/05/05/how-tfs-stores-files-and-calculated-deltas-on-versioned-files.aspx

Comment: In order of ascending size, they're mostly just images and videos, with a couple of zips. The sizes range anywhere from a few KB, up to the average of between 1MB-10MB, with a few 100MB whoppers. I've actually seen all the posts you link here before, but none of them mention FILESTREAM, which was what I was curious about.

Comment: My opinion is that the implementation details are Microsoft’s problem. The tool will easily accommodate your requirement. Out of interest what are the people with concerns proposing as an alternative to TFS?

Comment: @bwerks: no, there is no FILESTREAM, but TFS is designed to handle large files gracefully.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476611/large-files-in-source-control-tfs

Comment: @James Reed clear case, perforce, svn. I'm still hashing out what exactly the concerns are, but I don't estimate that TFS would be much worse, if worse at all, than competing products.

Comment: @Edward Thomson: you should post that as an answer, perhaps with any source material that tells you this! I'll mark it as such, since the answer containing this comment thread should, for SO purposes, not be approved.