# Storing 1024x768 bpp bitmaps in TFS

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfs, version-control

We would need to keep a number of *.bmp images (~50 MB) versioned (we do image comparison unit testing). So far I kept these files away from our main product TFS project because I was afraid that they could slow down GET operations, slow down TFS backup, because source control is not optimized for binaries and big files, etc.

Are my concerns legitimate or not?

Thanks.

Comment: might be interesting for you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476611/large-files-in-source-control-tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476611/large-files-in-source-control-tfs)

Comment: btw: tfs has a feature especially for comparing pictures [https://roadtoalm.com/2013/06/15/hidden-gems-in-tfs-2012part-9-image-compare-in-tfs-version-control/](https://roadtoalm.com/2013/06/15/hidden-gems-in-tfs-2012part-9-image-compare-in-tfs-version-control/)

Comment: [Manage and store large files in Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/manage-large-files)  and this thread for your reference  :https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80962/should-images-be-stored-in-a-git-repository

Answer (score 0):

In TFVC? Yes, that's a legitimate concern.

In Git, just use Git LFS for your binaries -- Git LFS stores pointers to blobs in the repo, and stores the blobs elsewhere. So typical source control operations (switching branches, commits, etc) are nice and fast and the repo itself is small.

Companies that deal with a lot of art assets (like game companies) typically use dedicated asset management software. However, I have no experience in that area so I can't provide much guidance.